# How do I get the computer to guess my number using divide and conqueror algorithm python

Tags: python-3.x

so I just started learning python and decided to do my first project. It is to get my computer to guess the number I'm thinking of using the divide and conqueror algorithm. As I was working on it, there were more questions than answer and I just decided to give up because it was too hard. Below is my code and I was wondering how can I implement the divide and conqueror algorithm to this program. Thank you for your help!

```
import math

highest = int(input("Enter the highest value you want me to guess: "))
lowest = 0
my_num = 42
computer_guess = ""


game = True

while game:
    while computer_guess != my_num:
        computer_guess = highest / 2
        if computer_guess > my_num:
            print("My num: ", my_num)
            print("Computer Guess: ", computer_guess)
            print("Computer guess is higher!")
            first_guess = computer_guess / 2
            third_guess = (second_guess + first_guess) / 2



        if computer_guess < my_num:
            print("My num: ", my_num)
            print("Computer Guess: ", computer_guess)
            second_guess = (first_guess + computer_guess) / 2 #37.5



        else:
            print("My num: ", my_num)
            print("Computer Guess: ", computer_guess)
            print("Computer got it!")
            game = False
```

Comment: Side note, what you're trying to code is not a "divide and conquer" algorithm as you're not breaking the problem into smaller problems and solving each to solve the whole. Here you're breaking a range down into two smaller ranges and simply discarding the range that does not contain the target. Not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a binary search. You start with a range `a` to `b`, pick the midpoint `m = (a+b)/2` and compare that to the target. If too low, your new range is `m` to `b`. If too high, your new range is `a` to `m`. Set those as the new `a` and `b` respectively and go again until you match the target.

```
a = 0  # lowest
b = int(input("Enter the highest value you want me to guess: "))  # highest
target = 42  # my_num
# no need to instantiate guess since you're only using that within the loop

while True:
    m = int((a + b) / 2)  # guess
    if m == target:
        print(f'Nailed it! The number was {m}.')
        break
    else:
        if m < target:
            print(f'Range {a}:{b} guess {m} < {target} Too low!')
            a = m
        else:
            print(f'Range {a}:{b} guess {m} > {target} Too high!')
            b = m
```

Comment: I should note that this method doesn't account for the case where the target is outside the initial range. If you want to include that possibility, you just need to add an extra test after setting the new range to see if `a == b` and `break`ing if true with some error message.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the problem you are talking about

```
import math

highest = int(input("Enter the highest value you want me to guess: "))
lowest = 0
my_num = 42
computer_guess = ""


game = True
first_guess=0
while game:
    highest = int(input("Enter the highest value you want me to guess: "))
    computer_guess = highest / 2
    if computer_guess > my_num:
        print("My num: ", my_num)
        print("Computer Guess: ", computer_guess)
        print("Computer guess is higher!")
        first_guess = computer_guess / 2
        third_guess = (second_guess + first_guess) / 2



    if computer_guess < my_num:
        print("My num: ", my_num)
        print("Computer Guess: ", computer_guess)
        second_guess = (first_guess + computer_guess) / 2 #37.5



    else:
        print("My num: ", my_num)
        print("Computer Guess: ", computer_guess)
        print("Computer got it!")
        game = False
```

After you try this code, you can continue development.
I don't fully understand the algorithm.